Can I hide seams using texture paint?
I have visually notable seam in my model:

Can I somehow hide this seam using texture paint? I know there is another ways to achive it using shading, but I'm planning to export this model to UE5, so I'm not sure it will have the same nodes as Blender. That's why I need to manipulate texture, not shader.
When I'm trying to use eyedropper and paint right in the same place, which color I've got - I'm getting this result:

so I suppose one of the problems is in blend mode, but other modes can't help me too - color is still different; and different parts of the mesh have different reactions on the same color:

What can I do? I'm not insisting on texture paint, but this is only way I know, which will work everywhere with the same (mostly) behavior.

Looks like the color picked is from another image overlay, but is this a single texture? I’d suggest looking at using the soften tool and smear tool to experiment there as it doesn’t look like a classic seam that is solved with clone tool.

@CraigDJones oh my god, you're absolutely right! The problem was I messed up materials. So now I need only to find a way to get smooth transition from head to body. Sorry, but I didn't understand, what is the soften tool and smear tool? Where I can find it?

In texture paint there are separate tools there in the tool panel, you can see an overview here https://youtu.be/4IsTnQU2f8A?si=-X2-upshuofNFcqe

@CraigDJones thank you. Unfortunately, youtube is banned in my country so I can't see video, but I founded this tools. Can you make an answer from your previous message, so I can accept it?

Ah, okay, I will set up some screen shots that can illustrate the tools we are talking about.

Here are some examples of the tools you can use to smooth and cover your visible seams, but in your case you might just use them to manipulate the patches of color.
Clone Tool works by using Ctrl key to place the 3d cursor where you want to clone from and grab pixels from that area to place under your brush. OR you can choose to load another image in the texture stack using a different UV with 'Clone from Paint Slot' where the image texture clone source can use a different UV mapping and not be directly connected to your node tree, just exists in an image node in your material.

Smear Tool works as it sounds, you should start with lower strength to make the best use here so that it doesn't break the texture and introduce artifacts. Useful for spreading pixels.

Soften Tool works like a Blur brush in other image editors, don't forget that you can also reverse it as a sharpen tool. This tool works best to add a finish before you use a Draw Tool at low strength to glaze a common color to blend.

Face Select Masking can be used with the Fill Tool to allow you to use a Gradient made up of two colors to control a blend in a problem area as well by limiting the reach of the Fill Tool. Set the Fill tool to Gradient and set the color stops to the ranges you are working with.


